# C++ - error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\Debug\gold-D.lib'

Tags: visual-c++

Hello everyone I am getting an error when I try to build an project in c++.

the error is LNK1104: cannot open file '..\Debug\gold-D.lib'

The gold-D.lib is present at that location but still I am getting an error .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are spaces in the file path, you may need to surround the file path with "".  Another possibility is that you don't have permission for the directory.